# Is there a way to add Activities/Tasks to the Sample Console?

Tags: tasks, activities, console

Just moving to a brand new org from one that is about 14 years old. We no longer have the old console type that we used to have access to and the new Sample Console does not allow Tasks... Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately adding the Activities or Tasks tab to the console isn't supported. One workaround for this would be to create a VF page and VF tab to recreate the listview you want

There is some good info on creating such a tab here
http://focusonforce.com/configuration/salesforce-activities-tab-and-list-view/

And once you do that you could add the tab to the console app to see it.